# How to run a hdfs cat command and read output file using Java

Tags: java, hdfs, inputstream, outputstream, software-quality

I need to run following command 'hdfs dfs -cat /user/username/data/20220815/EDHSB.CSV', which shows the contents of the CSV file (present in remote HDFS).

To implement the above I have used below code:

```
try{
    String shpath="hdfs dfs -cat /user/username/data/20220815/EDHSB.CSV";
    Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shpath);  
    ps.waitFor();  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Next step is to read the CSV file from above code.
Is the first step good enough or is there any other way for the entire flow...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`java.lang.Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html) and [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead, as that allows you to intercept the output directly in your Java code.

Basically, it looks like this

```java
final var process = new ProcessBuilder( "hdfs", "dfs", "-cat", "/user/username/data/20220815/EDHSB.CSV" )
  .start();
final String csvFileContents; 
try( var inputStream = process.getInputStream();
  var reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) )
{
  csvFileContents = lines.collect( Collectors.joining( "\n" ) );
}
```

All necessary error handling was omitted for readability …

Comment: This is not going to work because `ProcessBuilder` takes individual arguments instead of a whole line, so will try to look for a single executable file called "hdfs dfs -cat /user/username/data/20220815/EDHSB.CSV". On the other hand, `Runtime.exec` works ok for this. It also returns a `Process`, just like `ProcessBuilder.start()` does.

Comment: @k314159 – You're right; fixed it …

Answer (score 0):

Two things about your code:

1. It's better *not* to call `printStackTrace()` because it's too easy to miss it. Do something meaningful with exceptions. If you can't, just let the exception come out of your method by adding a `throws` clause to its signature.
2. Do you really want to wait for the process to finish by calling `waitFor()` before you start reading? If you do, and the file is very big, you might lose some content because the Java runtime has a limited buffer. Instead, get its inputstream and start process it straight away. You'll get an EOF condition when the process exits.

```
void processCSV() throws IOException {
    String shpath="hdfs dfs -cat /user/username/data/20220815/EDHSB.CSV";
    Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shpath);
    try (Stream<String> lines = ps.inputReader().lines()) {
        lines.forEach(line -> {
            processCSVLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```